# Raspberry Pi 4 with Anker PowerPort Speed 5

Tags: power-supply, pi-4

So I'm thinking of getting a Raspberry Pi 4 and I know they have raised the power requirements to 5v 3amps, rather than buying the offical power supply would using the two blue fast charge ports on my Anker PowerPort Speed 5 be okay with the specs below?

Here is a link to the item in question.

https://www.anker.com/products/variant/powerport-speed-5-ports/A2054111

Quick Charge 3.0 Output:3.6-6.5V=3A, 6.5-9V=2A, 9-12V=1.5A

PowerIQ Output:5V=4.8A (2.4A Max Per Port)

[image]

Kind regards,

Marcel

Comment: Spec says quick charge 3A at 3.6V to 6.5V.  Does this mean it will first quick charge P4 at 6.5V, quick fry it immediately. and short circuit current becomes 3A, and voltage drops to 3.6V? I visited Element 14 and they say there is an official P4 power supply, but no info is available.  Little Birds P4 kit (AUD99) includes a power supply, but not that impressive.

Comment: This is the official Raspberry Pi 4 15.3W [5.1V, 3A] USB-C Power Supply - https://static.raspberrypi.org/files/product-briefs/USB-C-Product-Brief.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Both USB 3 power delivery and Qualcomm Quick Charge ports default to 5V output, other voltages must be actively negotiated. RPi 4 doesn't support such negotiation protocols, so the voltage will stay at 5V.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up the Anker Powercore 10000 PD redux for my new Raspberry Pi 4 - and am getting periodic lightning bolt (aka under voltage) icons on my 7” Pi touch display - both at startup, and when launching apps.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PXMF52C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PXMF52C)

WiFi and v2 camera are in constant use streaming video - nothing is plugged into the USB/Ethernet/HDMI ports.

YMMV with this device - but I don’t think I’ll chance the SD card corruption.  Back to looking for a decent portable PSU for the Pi 4...

Answer (score 0):

So here’s the deal, it’s not likely that it will support it as it’s looking for certain things to enable it.  That being said, I have successfully powered and used my pi4 using an old Jarv rugged USB battery pack and a USB-A to USB-C wire.  Using it causes small but quite noticeable performance issues, the taskbar disappears when under any strain, the WiFi flickers on and off occasionally and the CPU will stutter.  I suspect that I could run the display on a separate power supply and it’d work much better but since the bank only has 1 output I can’t really test it without losing the touchscreen and stress testing.

But it does work...ish

Good luck,

Chris

Edit:  Oh yeah forgot to mention the lightning bolt being on the display that Dmitry mentioned.