# How to choose a power source for Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: power-supply

I bought a R-Pi some days ago. 
We all know raspberry pi needs 5V 3Amp to operate. I have these options for the power source:

1. I have an SMPS (Detached from a Desktop PC) which have 5 V and 15 Amp output.
2. I have a turbocharger(5V 2.85 Amp and 9 volt 1.5Amp)
3. A powerbank (Which support fastcharging with 5V 2 amp, 5V 2.5Amp and 5V 3 amp)
4. A normal power source.

There are so many confusions.  What if turbocharger throws 9 volt and burn everything?
What if the Raspberry Pi pulls a lot of ampere accidently?

Which option should I choose for powering up R-Pi4?
Is there any other way to power up Raspberry pi?

Comment: Try them, but #3 won't work. Or #5 just buy the Raspberry Pi Official power supply which is 100% guaranteed to work.

Comment: "We all know raspberry pi needs 5V 3Amp to operate." No we don't! The Foundation recommends a 3A supply, but the Pi4 itself runs quite happily on a 1A supply. The [Typical bare-board active current consumption](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-power) is 600mA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing a Pi4 power supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99983/choosing-a-pi4-power-supply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any 5V power source to safely power your Raspberry Pi, provided it can deliver the required current (3A in this case).

Raspberry Pi would not accidentally pull extra current. The circuitry will not allow that to happen. If your power source cannot deliver the current your device requires, the voltage drops and your device would shut down or give troubles.

You can also use a turbo charger that can deliver 5V among its range of voltages. These power sources don't switch to other power delivery mode, say 9V by itself, unless the device demands it. The smartphones that has ability to make use of fast charging capabilities send signals to the charger for more power, and it would switch it's output mode. Raspberry Pi doesn't do such thing, and thus it's safe.

Comment: Thanks Irfan for the answer.This means if I use only + and GND of the turbo charger then I am safe?

Comment: @Irfanuddin, I like your suggestion and explanation, which are concise and clear, beside professional and at the same newbie friendly.  Cheers.

Comment: @SohanArafat You can connect USB-C pin of your charger to Pi. It is safe.