# How to power RPi with fan from single source?

Tags: power, performance, alternative-power, cooling

Electronics beginner here. I have Raspberry Pi 4 GB variant. I have the following power requirements:

1. power a 5V cooling fan <strike>12V cooling fan (a spare cooler master)</strike><sup>thanks @Milliways</sup>
2. safely (i.e. avoiding both backcharging & over-volt/amp problems) power the board via GPIOs, I have to use OTG mode sometimes so I am not using the USB-C port for charging.

How can this be done in least cost?
Inspired by @tlfong01 comment on [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99983/choosing-a-pi4-power-supply) question, I am thinking a buying a 24v SMPS and divide its power between 1 & 2, but I don't know how to practically do it.

---

OTOH I already have a good fan, should I buy heat sink also?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are using OTG there is no way to avoid "backcharging" unless you design your own circuitry. Save yourself a lot of angst (and money) by purchasing a 5V fan. A fan will do little without a heatsink. You only need a tiny fan (and maybe not even this) . See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/thermal-testing-raspberry-pi-4/#comments