# Power Supply Raspberry pi 4

Tags: power-supply, pi-4, usb-power, power-management

I have googled a lot but didn't find anything useful. Can I use any power adapter other than the official Raspberry Pi supply?

Moreover, I have an Argon One Case and many people have recommended having a bit more watt power supplies, i.e 18 W. Due to lack of delivery to my country, I couldn't buy the official Argon One power supply, but I want to ask that can I buy any other 18W charger adapter to be used with Raspberry Pi 4, Baseus one, for example. If yes, do they need to be 3A/6V or 5V/2.5A or what? Really need help regarding my Raspberry Pi.

*I also have quite large number of hats to attach.*

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best option is a good quality power supply, as cheap brands may
>   say they are rated at 2.4 amps when they don't actually supply that
>   much. Based on the numerous bad experiences I've had with 3rd party
>   chargers, I'd highly recommend buying the official one from the
>   foundation! *[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100095/44221)*

**Short answer:** Looking for a `5V / 3Amps` power supply, not the cheapest one. Also, the official Raspberry Pi 4 power supply has a `5.1V / 3.0A` DC output

Comment: Will 6V/3A do any damage to my Raspberry pi instead of 5.1V/3A? Moreover, will any other charger saying **DYNAMIC** charging which can output 6V/3A as well as 9V/2A be doing any damage to it?

Comment: [Don’t go above the max of 5.25.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-highest-voltage-from-the-power-supply-a-Raspberry-Pi-4-can-handle-without-getting-damaged/answer/Andrew-Gulak-1)

Comment: What about Current? 3A or can be more?

Comment: @ChMuhammadSohaib [Too many amps is not a problem, the Pi will just consume what it needs.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6620#p84490)